# How to hide a certain page link using wp_list_pages() in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In my footer I list my page link like this:

```
<ul id="footer-links" class="list-unstyled">
    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
</ul>
```

And I have an output like this:

```
<ul id="footer-links" class="list-unstyled">

    <li class="page_item page-item-4"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/">Top Page</a></li>

    <!-- I want to hide this page link -->
    <li class="page_item page-item-18 page_item_has_children current_page_ancestor current_page_parent"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/about-intra-mart/">About Intra-Mart</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="page_item page-item-81"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/about-intra-mart/changes-corporate-competitiveness/">Changes Corporate Competitiveness</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-85"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/about-intra-mart/effects-of-adopting-intra-mart/">Effects of adopting Intra-Mart</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-93 current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/about-intra-mart/examples-of-adoptation-of-intra-mart/">Examples of adoptation of Intra-Mart</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-91"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/about-intra-mart/features-of-intra-mart/">Features of Intra-Mart</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/company-profile/">Company Profile</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/products/">Products</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-10"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/services/">Services</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-12"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/download/">Download</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-20"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/case-study/">Case Study</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-22"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/news/">News</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-24"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/resources/">Resources</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-26"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/partner/">Partner</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-30"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-14"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-28"><a href="http://localhost/nttdata/site-map/">Site Map</a></li>

</ul>
```

I want to hide the list with a class of `page-item-18` and also the sub link under with it.

How can I achieve this in Wordpress?
I am new in Wordpress.

That's all. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible exclude certain pages.

Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Try to update your code as follows,

```
<ul id="footer-links" class="list-unstyled">
    <?php wp_list_pages(array('title_li' => '', 'exclude' => '18')); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: For multiple values: Define a comma-separated list of Page IDs to be excluded from the list (example: 'exclude=3,7,31')

Comment: Cool, I hope this helped  :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try this code
<ul id="footer-links" class="list-unstyled">
    <?php wp_list_pages(array('title_li' => __('Pages'),'exclude'  => array( 2, 5 ),'post_type'=> 'page')); ?>
</ul>
```